# Web App Interfacing with iOS app for push notifications

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have a basic web app that is able to send push notifications (via UrbanAirship) to my iOS app.

My questions is, how can my webapp know that I have a new iOS app user? So I can then put the push DeviceID into a database (along with other data as required).

i.e. what is the interface for getting data into the Webapp, is it new code in the iOS app, or is there some other interface from UA?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an iOS developer, so it's hard for me to be too specific, but I'm assuming you need to store a device ID and (possibly) a token so that you can send messages to that device. I'm assuming (also) that you have access to this information on the device.

The correct way to do this would be to create datastore table of devices and the information associated with them (tokens, various IDs, I also like to have the last time I sent them a message, etc.) Then you send a request (should be a POST request, semantically) to your app when the user registers their device. Send the information you need in the POST request, then store it in your datastore through a handler.

Hope that helps? That's how things are done with Android Cloud to Device messages, and from my quick perusal of Urban Airship, that's how their service works, too.

Comment: Your answer was just what I was looking for. Lost my whole Sunday to investigating POST.